# .NET Website Huge Peak Working Set Memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, memory-leaks, iis-7

I have an asp.net/c# 4.0 website on a shared server.

The os Windows Server 2012 is running IIS 7, has 32GB of ram and 3.29GHz of processor.

The server is running into difficulty now and again, such as problems RDP'ing and other PHP websites running slow.

Our sys admin has suggested my website as being a possible memory hog and cause of these issues.

At any given time the sites "Memory (private working set)" is 2GB and can peak as high as 15GB.

I ran a trial version of **JetBrains dotMemory** on the server, attached to the website's w3wp.exe process. My first time using this program, I am a complete novice here.

I took two memory snapshots using dotMemory.

And the basic snapshot comparison can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Oksl.jpg

From the above comparison we can see that System.String and BusinessObjects.Item are the two items with the most survived bytes.

Drilling down on system.string I could see that the main dominating survived object was **System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry with 135MB**. See the screengrab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvWYy.jpg

Which leads me to suspect maybe I cache too much?

I cache all data that comes out of my database: HTML Page Content, Nav-Menu Items, Relationships between pages & children, articles etc. Using **HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert**.

With the cache timeout set to 10080 minutes.

**My Questions:**

1 - is 2GB Memory (private working set) and a peak as high as 15GB to much for a server with 32 GB Ram?

2 - Have I used dotMemory correctly to identify an issue?

3 - Is my caching an issue?

4 - Possible other causes?

5 - Possible solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Some more screengrabs from dotMemory: http://imgur.com/3ir5OFc

Comment: Can you describe your code? There are List<string>()? Particular classes?

Comment: @Tinwor - there are many many Lists<Item> stored in the cache. Item is my custom class which has properties like PageBody which stores the body html of a news article. Ther are also Many individual Item stored in the cache.

Comment: It's not a good pratice what are you doing. I suggest to you to get the information from db only when you need. Also you burn ram(think about this: a List of 500 element and there are 500 Istance of this list, one for every user)

Comment: @Tinwor I only hit the DB when i need to - this is why i use the cache. Instead of hitting the DB every time i store it in the cache. The cache is server cache - therefore only one instance even if 500 users. The server cahce is shared by all users - correct?

Comment: So you are using Application variables to store data?

Comment: @Tinwor no I'm using HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert

Comment: Mhh... I'm not sure that it could be this, probably it's an infinite loop. You' ve tried to the bug the cycles?

Comment: @Tinwor - thanks anyway. I am not sure what you mean by 'debug the cycles'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of a large amount of memory itself can not slow down a program. It can be slowed down

1. if windows actively using swap file. Ask an admin to check this case
2. if .NET program causes garbage collecting too much (produces too much memory traffic)

You can see a memory traffic information in dotMemory. Unfortunately it can't gather such information if it attaches to the program, the only way to collect object creation stack traces and memory traffic information is to launch your program under dotMemory profiler, enabling corresponding settings.

**BUT!**
The problem is you can't evaluate is memory traffic amount "N" high or no, the only way to find a root of **a performance problem** is using **performance profiler**.

For example JetBrains dotTrace can show you, how much time you program spends in garbage collecting, and only in case this is a bottle neck, you should use memory profiler to find a root of traffic.

Conclusion: try to find a bottle neck using performance profiler first. 
Then, if you still have a questions about dotMemory, ask me, I'll try to help you :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, the sys admin says that it is using a swap file by default because its Windows Server 2012, he did not set up a swap file but he says that windows has them by default. Not my area so I wouldn't know. So - Would "Memory (private working set)" at 2GB and peak as high as 15GB be an issue on this Windows Server 2012 with 32GB ram? I will look into what you said about performance profiler.

Comment: "Would "Memory (private working set)" at 2GB and peak as high as 15GB be an issue on this Windows Server 2012 with 32GB ram?"
In my opinion it can't be an issue (source of performance problem).

Comment: Ok thank you - I am marking this as answered, because: The reason the site was marked by our sys admin as a *possible* issue was because he saw its large memory usage. Not its processor performance. Therefore its memory usage seems to be irrelevant to the server issues. Along with this, the sys admin has identified an issue with PHP sites on the server that we now believe might be the issue.

Comment: the only way to collect object creation stack traces and memory traffic information is to launch your program under dotMemory profiler, enabling corresponding settings.  Why it has this limitions? @Ed.ward ? I have an asp.net app. It need to build very huge local cache. Attatch the dotMemory with settings cause the app can't build all cache or it will causes two hours to build part of the caches.